# How to process user defined json format in D3.js

Tags: json, d3.js

I have a json File that is in the format. I would like to access each branch and sub branch of this file using d3.js

```
"x":
   {
      "a":
        {
              no.of employees:30
              total salary:2500000
              count_email:25
         }
       "b":
         {
              no.of employees:20
              total salary:350000
              count_email:25

           }
     }

   "y":
     {

       "c":
         {
              no.of employees:30
              total salary:4500000
              count_email:30

           }
      }
   "z":
     {
       "d":
         {
              no.of employees:40
              total salary:550000
              count_email:40
         }
       "e":
         {
              no.of employees:10
              total salary:100000
              count_email:15

         }
        "f":
         {
              no.of employees:15
              total salary:1500000
              count_email:15

         }
    }
```

How can i access each branch and sub branch for processing. How to know the keys of this json format

Answer (score 0):

Your Json is in a wrong format : 
Before anything, validate it with a tool like JsonLint.com.
It should look something like that :

```
data = {
"x": [{
    "a": {
        "ff": 30,
        "fff": 2500000,
        "fff": 25
    },
    "b": {
        "ff": 30,
        "fff": 2500000,
        "fff": 25
    }
}],
"y": [{
    "a": {
        "ff": 30,
        "fff": 2500000,
        "fff": 25
    },
    "b": {
        "ff": 30,
        "fff": 2500000,
        "fff": 25
    }
}]


};
```

You could iterate into your object like that :

```
Employee = [];
for (x in data) {
// Access to the first level
  for (y in x) {
  //Access to the second level

    console.log(data[x][y]);
   // Here you could store each of your object into a new tab that you could use in d3.js
     Employee.push(data[x][y]);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing special in D3 to do this.

You can use simple javascript to deal with this case.

Something like this:

```
d3.json("my.json", function(error, json) { //load json using d3
  if (error) return console.warn(error);
  var keys = Object.keys(json); //get all the keys
  console.log(keys, "Branch") //print on console
  keys.forEach(function(key){
    var subBranch = Object.keys(json[key]); //get all subbranch for key
    console.log(subBranch, "SubBranch of " + key); //print subbranch and key
  })
});
```

will produce output like this:

```
["x", "y", "z"] "Branch"
["a", "b"] "SubBranch of x"
["c"] "SubBranch of y"
["d", "e", "f"] "SubBranch of z"
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/fvEuunCmDBOgCH6L6BWg?p=preview)

Comment: it showing TypeError: can't convert undefined to object
<anonymous>
 demd3.html:10
d3.json/<()
 d3.v2.js:2950
ready()
 d3.v2.js:2940
d3.xhr/req.onreadystatechange()
 d3.v2.js:2933

Comment: sorry i didnt get what are you trying to do here..who is showing _TypeError: can't convert undefined to object_ my plunk works as expected check console..

Comment: I think you are facing the error because you JSON is not in the correct format please check my plunk for  corrected format.

Comment: the data format is mentioned in the question , but the format is valid JSON

Comment: Please use this site https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to validate your JSON it misses commas and has other issues. This will help you overcome it.